# CFrame Bullet Will Not Fire

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

Recently, I have been experimenting in the Roblox version of Lua in the studio. I tried to hook up a moving projectile to a GUI button. Here is the code:

```
local cannonp1 = workspace.CannonP1
local loopingvar = 0

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(fire)

function fire()
    repeat until loopingvar == 100
        workspace.ProjectileP1.CFrame = workspace.ProjectileP1.CFrame * CFrame.new(1, 0, 0)
        loopingvar = loopingvar + 1
        wait(0.1)
    end
end
```

I am very new to Roblox Studio, so all I can say is that When I press the button, not a single thing happens to my projectile. And the projectile is anchored, if you were wondering. I know that good questions should be elaborate, but there is no other information that i can find that would effect the movement of the projectile other than my extremely poor scripting. I have also checked on the Roblox developer forums, but most of the posts about CFrame there are outdated and do not work in the new version of Roblox Studio. I have checked about every website possible, but to no avail. Any advice would be **amazing.**

Answer (score 1):

You're not using `repeat until` correctly. The first line is supposed to be `repeat` and the last line is supposed to be `until loopingvar == 100`. There's not supposed to be an `end` at all. Currently, there's a syntax error in your code due to the extra `end`, and even without that, you'd have an infinite loop, since it's basically `repeat --[[do nothing]] until loopingvar == 100`.

However, you can do even one step better than this, by using a numeric `for` loop. Instead of the above changes, get rid of `local loopingvar = 0` and `loopingvar = loopingvar + 1`, and replace `repeat until loopingvar == 100` with `for loopingvar = 0,100 do`.

Comment: Even when I fix the repeat command (I tried both ways) nothing happens to my projectile when i **fully left click** the button. Is this a problem with my function? Or my CFrame usage?

Comment: @Hello-Ya What's the difference between "fully left click" and a regular click? What kind of click does it work on?

Comment: Instead of just activating on click down or click up, the user must complete a full left click to activate the button.

Comment: @Hello-Ya Does it work better if you use `MouseButton1Down`/`MouseButton1Up` instead of `MouseButton1Click`?